# What is the use of sql builder in PetaPoco?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, petapoco, micro-orm

I have this code in petapoco

```
public List<T> Fetch<T>(Sql sql)
{
            return Fetch<T>(sql.SQL, sql.Arguments);
}
```

Which inherently calling Fetch method which takes a string as parameter.
Then why do we need sql builder in petapoco?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sql.Builder is a [fluent API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) and gives the ability to **conditionally** build SQL. Which makes formatting SQL strings easy and provides a mechanism to use proper parameter replacements to protect from [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

**Example not tested**

```
var sql = PetaPoco.Sql.Builder()
    .Select("*")
    .From("Orders.Product")
    .Where("OrderID = @0", id);
```

[From PetaPoco documentation](http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/):

> Fetch returns a List<> of POCO's

Comment: Thank you @william for your answer. We can also prevent SQL injection by using parameters in string overload of Fetch method. So is it just for formatting SQL strings?

Comment: It's for allowing you to conditionally build SQL. So yes based on what you pass to the Builder, it will format the SQL correctly so you don't have to worry about it. That is the basic premise.